# Royal Mail API Error: httpCode":"404", "httpMessage":"Not Found", "moreInformation":"No resources match requested URI

Tags: php, curl

I have the following on a page:

```html
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.royalmail.net/***/summary",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json",
    "x-ibm-client-id: ***",
    "x-ibm-client-secret: ***"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

I have everything authorised from Royal Mail end and when run in Royal Mail sandbox it provides the desired results but when run from a page on my server it returns:

{ "httpCode":"404", "httpMessage":"Not Found", "moreInformation":"No resources match requested URI" }

Could anyone point me in the right direction to what could be causing this issue.

Comment: Presumably the URL you're making the request to doesn't contain '`***`' and that's just there to remove some sensitive information from your question? Check that the URL is actually accessible (returns HTTP 200 status) from your server. Are you actually executing the script from an Internet-accessible web server - i.e. not from your local machine (`http://localhost` or a local address)? Would also recommend you look at https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPGET.html instead of using `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET"`

Comment: That URL is not accessible via the internet but I was under the impression that with my ID and Secret that it would authenticate my call? I have replaced the official values with *** instead of the proper details just as they are sensitive

Comment: It looks to me like an issue at Royal Mail's end, as opposed to something in your script. If you're saying the same code works with their sandbox it's likely that the account isn't "live" and is effectively only working under their test (sandbox) environment. Some other systems (e.g. SagePay) work in this way until the account is made live. Some services will also only work from a hostname which can be resolved (i.e. not `http://localhost`) and may require the domain/IP address adding so they know not to accept requests coming from elsewhere. I think this is an account problem, not a code one.

Comment: Essentially the code is working because it's making the curl request. The error message returned - which is coming from `api.royalmail.net` -  tells you all you need to know - the URL you're requesting is considered invalid (not found) as far as Royal Mail are concerned. So it's an issue for them, not something wrong in the code - unless the URL itself has been specified incorrectly, e.g. a typo has been made, which happens more than you may think.